# Why does the series diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n n$ diverge?

Is it because the expanded series:

$ -1 + 2 -3 + 4 -5 + 6... $

is the difference between the infinite sum of the even and odd numbers which would be infinity?

Comment: If you attempt to use the alternate series test, one of the main conditions fail so what do you conclude?

Comment: I was under the impression that the alternating series test gives conditions for convergence and not divergence. So if we fail a condition for the test, we can't apply the test and not that the series diverges.

Comment: Convergence means that the partial sums come closer and closer to some number 8the limit). What are the partial sums in your case?

Comment: the limit condition is vital. May I ask... do you know Dirichlet's test? Note that the second condition of the alternate series test for a series $\sum (-1)^{n}a_{n}$ is the most important condition for convergence if the $\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_{n}\neq0$, then automatically the series $\sum (-1)^{n}a_{n}$ does not converge. Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173634/alternating-series-test-question-if-it-fails-what-does-it-mean

Comment: The partial sums are $-1,1,-2,2,-3,3-4,4,...$ can you conclude ?

Comment: I think I get it. If we simplify the partial sums we are basically summing 1 infinity times so  it diverges.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the nth term test for divergence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

If $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n \ne 0$, then the series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

A series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if the sequence of partial sums, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$, i.e.
\begin{align*}
&a_1 \\
&a_1 + a_2 \\
&a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \\
&a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
converges in the sense of sequences. In the case of the given series, the partial sums come to:
\begin{align*}
-1 &= -1 \\
1 &= -1 + 2 \\
-2 &= -1 + 2 - 3 \\
2 &= -1 + 2 - 3 + 4 \\
-3 &= -1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 \\
3 &= -1 + 2 - 3 + 4 - 5 + 6 \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
One can prove the pattern emerging with induction if they wish (or indeed by simply grouping and summing pairs of consecutive terms), but what is clear is that the sequence of partial sums is oscillating, positive and negative, while getting larger and larger. This prevents the partial sums from converging, and hence prevents the series from converging.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method 1

Try grouping 2 terms at a time
$-1+2-3+4-5+...$
$=(-1+2)+(-3+4)+(-5+6)+...$
$=1+1+1+...$
$=∞$

#### Method 2

$-1=-1$
$-1+2=1$
$-1+2-3=-2$
$-1+2-3+4=2$
$-1+2-3+4-5=-3$
$-1+2-3+4-5+6=3$
As we can observe the sequence doesn't seem to(and will not) converge at a particular points on the number line